# Zoom effect on buttons inside a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming, flowlayoutpanel

I have some buttons inside a FLP and I want when the mouse is over a button, to increase the size of the button a little, like a zoom effect. The problem is that when the button size increases, all buttons next to it slide to the right and down.. Probably the issue is caused by the space added by the FLP between items, but how can I prevent this, so when the size is increasing to go over that space not to add more..?

My ZOOM class:

```
class zoom
    {
        public zoom(Control cst)
        {
            cst.MouseEnter += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                cst.Size = new Size(70, 75);    
                cst.Font = new Font(cst.Font.FontFamily, 9);                    
            };
            cst.MouseLeave += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               cst.Size = new Size(68, 73);
               cst.Font = new Font(cst.Font.FontFamily, 8);
            };
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the way the FlowLayoutPanel works. It moves the rest of the controls to fit them all following the flow.
If you have some space between the buttons it's because of the Margin property, you could reduce the margin of the button as you zoom it. 
This won't work if you want the button to show over the other ones. In that case, probably the only way to go is to use a simple Panel instead of the FlowLayoutPanel and do a BringToFront() with the Zoom.

Comment: i don't want the button to show over others, only to make it a little bigger. I will try to reduce the margins. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, and looking the Sizes reducing a pixel of the margin of each side you'll be alright. ;) Good luck.